# Is "Both of our child" valid?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

> Child: I am Papa's child. I am Mama's child.
>   Mama: Oh, so you are both of our child?

Is Mama's reply correct?

I want to use *"both of"* in my reply. How should I form the sentence if the above sentence is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Child: I am Papa's child. I am Mama's child.
>
> Mama: Oh, so you are both of our child?

*Both X* or *both of X* means *two/a pair of X together*.  There is one child, so *both* can't be used this way to refer to the child (keep reading, though).

There are two parents, which form a pair, so you want to use *both* referring to them.  This is likely what you are looking for:

> Mama: Oh, so you are the child of both of us?

or

> Mama: Oh, so you are the child of us both?

---

Now, if the parents were responding to the child with a joke or sarcastic retort, then Mama might say:

> Mama: Oh, so you are both of our children?

The plural of *child* is *children* and since *both* refers to two things what follows has to be a plural.

Answer (score 3):

> Oh, so you are both of our child?

is incorrect. You can't say *you are both*, because *both* refers to *you*, and there is only one of you. I would say:

> Mama: Oh, so you are our child?

This automatically implies both parents, when Mama says "our".

To write this concept using "both":

> Mama: Oh, so you are a/the child of both of us?

Comment: For me, "our" must be emphasized in "you are our child" for this to have the right meaning in context: "Oh, so you are *our* child?"

Comment: Or, if Mom wants to tease the child as to its parentage, emphasize *are*: "Oh, so you *are* our child?